# Script inside Ajax PHP File

Tags: php, ajax

I am coding a program where i am fetching divs using a script name "awesome-grid.js", but i am facing issue while getting data through AJAX. this script not working and divs coming in wrong layouts.

```js
function getload()
{
$.ajax({
data:'&task=results',
type:'post',
url:'ajax/ajaxLoadData.php',
success: function(result)
{ document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = result;
}
});
}
```

```
Above is a script using for ajax.
```

Comment: send your variable  as `data:{task:results},`

Comment: Thanks for respond, i am sending data in the same way... but what issue coming is my divs are loading through JS file which is in header but when i am trying to load through AJAX the header js file not making divs as they must have to be in layout.